# javascript_include_tag recursively include directory in assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a directory in app/assets/javascripts called libs. And it includes a lot of javascript files in additional to subdirectories with javascript files. I want to include them at the bottom of my page right before the closing body tag. What is the best approach to do this?

I have tried:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "libs/**/*.js" %>
```

but that produces a 404 Not Found in chrome console.

I have tried this:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag *Dir[Rails.root.join("app/assets/javascripts/libs/**/*.js")] %>
```

but it gives me the error:

> Asset filtered out and will not be served: add
>   `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(
>   libs/autosize/jquery.autosize.js )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb`
>   and restart your server

I assume that require_tree (which will require all the contents of a directory recursively) cannot be used in application.html.erb or other view templates. So what other options do I have to include all the javascripts from one particular directory inside the assets directory inside application.html.erb?

Comment: Why not put them in the `lib/assets/javascripts/` or `vendor/assets/javascripts/` directories?

Comment: Whats the benefit of doing that?

Comment: Checkout out [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization) section in the rails guides regarding asset organization. I assumed that since the directory is called `libs`, `lib/assets/javascripts/` would be a better place to store your files. Then you could put `<%= javascript_include_tag *Dir[Rails.root.join("lib/assets/javascripts/**/*.js")] %>` in your view. Finally, add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( **/*.js )` to your `config/initializers/assets.rb` file and restart the server.